# how to fetch record monthly total in select query in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am having following output of query

[image]

**Query:**

```
SELECT DATENAME(mm, date) [Month], sum(braekTime) [TotalBreakTime],
sum(DATEPART(hh,totalTime) * 60 + DATEPART(mi,totalTime) + DATEPART(ss,totalTime) * 0.017) [Minute],firstName
    FROM employeeAttendance,employee
    where FK_employeeId = employee.employeeId
    GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, date),firstName
    ORDER BY [Month]
```

but **I want each n every month record with null/ 0 value**
like June and July record is not available then it should display like following

```
Month    TotalBreakTime   Minute   firstName    
-----    --------------   ------    ---------
January       0           0           NULL
February      0           0           NULL
March         0           0           NULL
April         0           0           NULL
May           50          1015.000    foramaa 
June          0            0          NULL
July          0            0          NULL     
 .... Like till Dec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a virtual table or subquery for the months, and left join it to the totals query.

eg

```
select * from
(
    select number, datename(m,DATEADD(m, number-1, 0)) as monthname 
    from master..spt_values 
    where type='p' and number between 1 and 12
) months
    left join
(your totals query) totals
    on months.monthname = totals.month
```

Comment: A calendar table would also help to write cleaner SQL

Comment: @podiluska Please correct following line in your answer `on months.monthname = totals.month`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
;with cte as(
select 1 as rn union all select 2 union all select 3),
 cte1 as (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by c1.rn) as row_num
from cte cross join cte c1 cross join cte c2)
select * from cte1
left join
(SELECT DATENAME(mm, date) [Month], 
       sum(braekTime) [TotalBreakTime],
       sum(DATEPART(hh,totalTime) * 60 + DATEPART(mi,totalTime) + DATEPART(ss,totalTime) * 0.017) [Minute],
       firstName
FROM employeeAttendance join employee
on FK_employeeId = employee.employeeId
GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, date),firstName
ORDER BY [Month])B
on B.[Month]=DateName( month , DateAdd( month ,cte1.row_num , 0 ) - 1 )
and cte1.row_num <=12
```